# Multilingual smart dial in HTC One X

Tags: languages, htc-one-x, htc, phone-app

I have HTC One X with default firmware and the latest updates installed. I'm totally fine with the default dialer, but the only feature missing is Russian (Cyrillic) symbols in Smart Dialer. It's where you type T9 versions of names to fast filter your contact list.

Is there a way to add Russian symbols to default Smart Dialer? I want to use both English and Russian symbols simultaneously.

I can use separate app for that, like [ExDialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modoohut.dialer&hl=en), it does exactly what I want. But I don't want to blunt Occam's razor.

Default dialer is to the left. ExDialer is to the right, since it is doing it right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that when I set system language to Russian, Smart Dialer adds Russian letters. I used [MoreLocale2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale) to add Russian system language. And I had to use the ["pm grant"](http://droider.eu/2013/07/22/morelocale-2-not-working-on-4-2-2-without-su-or-pm/) trick to make MoreLocale2 work.